# Populating 2nd+ column of listbox on Excel worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, excel-2007

I have an ActiveX listbox on an Excel 2007 worksheet. I want to populate it directly, not by pointing its RowSource property to a range, because there is no range that has the desired values.

The listbox's ColumnCount is set to 2.
I set ColumnWidths to "20;20", and now it returns:
20 pt;20 pt

So as far as I understand, two columns in the listbox should be available for writing, right?

Populating the first column is no problem:

```
activesheet.lstApplyCurves.List = array("Select All","Deselect All","aaa","bbb","ccc")
```

(or)

```
activesheet.lstApplyCurves.additem
activesheet.lstApplyCurves.List(0,0) = "Col1, Row1"
```

But how do I populate column 2? I get an error 380 ("Could not set the list property. Invalid property value.") on this:

```
activesheet.lstApplyCurves.List(0,1) = "Col2, Row1"
```

FWIW I've also tried this, but get the same error:

```
activesheet.lstApplyCurves.List(1,1) = "Col2, Row2"
```

So...how do I set values in the 2nd column?

UPDATE:

In addition to the answer below, FWIW I also found it's possible to assign a mulit-dimensional array to the List property, which is faster:

```
Dim ArrayToListbox() As Variant
ReDim ArrayToListbox(0 To 4, 0 To 2)
ArrayToListbox(0, 0) = "Select All"
ArrayToListbox(1, 0) = "Deselect All"
ArrayToListbox(2, 0) = "Row1-Col1"
ArrayToListbox(2, 1) = "Row1-Col2"
ArrayToListbox(2, 2) = "Row1-Col3"
ArrayToListbox(3, 0) = "Row2-Col1"
ArrayToListbox(3, 1) = "Row2-Col2"
ArrayToListbox(3, 2) = "Row2-Col3"
ArrayToListbox(4, 0) = "Row3-Col1"
ArrayToListbox(4, 1) = "Row3-Col2"
ArrayToListbox(4, 2) = "Row3-Col3" '"(" & Join(Array("a", "b", "c"), "|") & ")"
ActiveSheet.lstApplyCurves.Clear
ActiveSheet.lstApplyCurves.ColumnCount = 3
ActiveSheet.lstApplyCurves.List = ArrayToListbox
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. If the below doesn't work on your system then delete the listbox and re-create it and then try this code again.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ListBox1
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 2

        For i = 1 To 2
            .AddItem
            .List(i - 1, 0) = "Col1, Row" & i
            .List(i - 1, 1) = "Col2, Row" & i
        Next i

    End With
End Sub
```

[image]