# Error 381 populating listbox from a sheet table

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting all the time error 381.. What is there wrong? If i use only 1 column it works, if i add 2nd and more it stops working.

I try to populate my rows which compile with "if statement".

it stops each time to work at 2nd column.

UserForm + some Data:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hfCAu2m7C4kISSPJSvyjWc-TvxBr-fOO

2nd Version of code:

```
  Sub PopulateList2()
   Dim rngName As Range
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim LastRow As Long

   Set ws = E1G


  With ListBoxAbg
  .Clear
  .ColumnCount = 2

  LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

For i = 1 To LastRow
  If ws.Cells(i, 6).Value < Now() _
And ws.Cells(i, 6).Value <> vbNullString Then
      .AddItem
      .List(i - 1, 0) = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
      .List(i - 1, 1) = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value

 End If
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

....

```
 Sub PopulateList2()
  Dim rngName As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim LastRow As Long

  Set ws = E1G



AbgeListField.Clear
AbgeListField.ColumnCount = 7

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

For i = 1 To LastRow
If ws.Cells(i, 6).Value < Now() _
And ws.Cells(i, 6).Value <> vbNullString Then
   AbgeListField.AddItem ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
   AbgeListField.List(i - 1, 1) = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
   AbgeListField.List(i - 1, 2) = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
   AbgeListField.List(i - 1, 3) = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
   AbgeListField.List(i - 1, 4) = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
   AbgeListField.List(i - 1, 5) = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
   AbgeListField.List(i - 1, 6) = ws.Cells(i, 7).Value
  End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679082/populating-2nd-column-of-listbox-on-excel-worksheet

Comment: doesn't work for me. There is something wrong. That same error every time

Comment: Are you sure, you added the item as shown in that post and not as `AbgeListField.AddItem ws.Cells(i, 1).Value` ?

Comment: See 2nd version of the code. I changed it as in example from you. Is it possible to get that data with other commands than with those`ws.Cells(i, 2).Value`? it's in excel table.

Comment: You mean to say without looping show a range in LB?

Comment: I need to loop ma table to get the right ones with `date < Date(now)`. That code finds always the frist row with that data and can't get the result form the cell. The first row is i=40, but somehow it breaks by getting the data

Comment: If I edit that so: `.AddItem ws.Cells(i, 1).Value` and run it only for 1 column. I get my results. But if i decide to add 2nd it breaks on that line with **Error 1004**. It works only with `.AddItem ws.Cells(i, 1). I made 2 lines with add item, i got right result but only in one column. Is there property for `.additem` to chose target column in listbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer in that post:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f5619db9-be72-41e3-a353-54ebb021f936/runtime-error-381-could-not-set-the-list-property-invalid-property-array-index?forum=exceldev

i added new `dim nxtItme As Long`. it works perfect now:

```
Sub PopulateList2()
 Dim rngName As Range
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim nxtItem As Long

 Set ws = E1G
 nxtItem = 0

 With ListBoxAbg
  .Clear
  .ColumnCount = 6

  LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

For i = 1 To LastRow
  If ws.Cells(i, 6).Value < Now() _
  And ws.Cells(i, 6).Value <> vbNullString Then

.AddItem
.List(nxtItem, 0) = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
.List(nxtItem, 1) = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
.List(nxtItem, 2) = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
.List(nxtItem, 3) = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
.List(nxtItem, 4) = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
nxtItem = nxtItem + 1

  End If
 Next i
End With

End Sub
```